# R Changing Elements in a Dataframe

Tags: r, replace, element, strsplit

I'm trying to, as the title says, change elements from my dataframe from one character to another. The dataframe is as follows:

```
g1=c("CC","DD","GG")
g2=c("AA","BB","EE")
g3=c("HH","II","JJ")

df=data.frame(g1,g2,g3)
```

I wish to convert the elements from letterletter format to letter/letter format (e.g. CC to C/C or AA to A/A)

I know using "strsplit" would work on a list.
I also know that I would need to somehow incorporate: collapse="/"

How would I be able to apply the strsplit function to the entire dataframe?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
split=function(x)
{
  unlist(paste(strsplit(x,""),collapse="/"))
}

j=as.data.frame(apply(df,1,split))
```

but it doesn't give the desired results.

Update----------------
Apparently, the following script works:

```
split=function(x)
{
  paste(unlist(strsplit(x,"")),collapse="/")
}

p=apply(df,c(1,2),split)
```

If there is a more efficient or convenient way, please feel free to share.

Comment: Is it safe to use `split` function name? There's already a base package function named that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of two ways to approach this.  One is using `strsplit` like you did.  You were only missing the portion where you loop over each element in the list returned from `strsplit`:

```
Split <- function(x) {
  #unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, ""), paste, collapse="/"))
  sapply(strsplit(x, ""), paste, collapse="/")
}
as.data.frame(lapply(df, Split))
```

Another approach would be to use `gsub` and the `\\B` symbol, which matches the empty string that isn't at the beginning or end of a "word".

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, gsub, pattern="\\B", replacement="/"))
```

What constitutes a "word" depends on locale and implementation, so here's another solution using `gsub` and back-references.

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, gsub, pattern="(.)(.)", replacement="\\1/\\2"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with a function definition like this

```
insertslash <- function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(x) paste(x, collapse="/"))
```

Convince yourself that it does what it should by `insertslash(g1)`.

To apply it to all columns of the dataframe, do this:

```
as.data.frame(apply(df, 2, insertslash))
```

Obviously, you can roll this into one nasty one-liner:

```
as.data.frame(apply(df, 2, function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(x) paste(x, collapse="/"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of a hack using `gsub`. Someone who knows more about regex ought to be able to improve on this:

```
mySplit <- function(x)
{
  substr(gsub("","/",x),2,4)
}

as.data.frame(apply(df,2,mySplit))
```

The reason your original solution wasn't working was because you were `unlist`ing at the wrong spot. So if you `unlist` later and use `lapply` things work as you might expect:

```
mySplit1 <- function(x)
{
  unlist(lapply(strsplit(x,""),paste,collapse="/"))
}

as.data.frame(apply(df,2,mySplit1))
```

Comment: I just tested that, and what comes out is:
'g1=c("C/C","D/D","G/G")
 g2=g1
 g3=g1
 data.frame(g1,g2,g3)'

Answer (score 0):

Another hack using paste(), definitely not as elegant but it gets the job done.

```
for (col in 1:ncol(df)){
  df[,col] = paste(substr(df[,col],1,1),"/",substr(df[,col],1,1), sep="")
}
```